# How can I read WKT from the shapefile .prj?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, postgis, shapefile, map-projections

I am building a system which lets users upload shapefiles.  It then converts those shapefiles to PostGIS using `shp2pgsql`. This command requires the SRS ID in form of an EPSG code.

So I need a ruby gem that can read the shapefile's `*.prj` file (which contains the projection/spatial reference system encoded as WKT) and return a corresponding SRS ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how Ruby bindings work to GDAL, but OSR (part of GDAL) can extract either the projection WKT (text) or the SRID (integer).

See [this gis.SE answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/shapefile-prj-to-postgis-srid-lookup-table/7615#7615) for a solution with Python/GDAL/OSR.

**Update:** It turns out the Ruby bindings work nicely as expected. To get you going, try this code:

```
require 'gdal/osr'

prj_fname = 'myfile.prj'
prj = File.open( prj_fname )

# Import the WKT from the PRJ file
srs = Gdal::Osr::SpatialReference.new()
srs.import_from_wkt( prj.read )

# Various exports
puts srs.export_to_wkt

srs.auto_identify_epsg
puts srs.get_authority_name(nil)
puts srs.get_authority_code(nil)
```

If you need some other aspect of the projection, explore the available public methods:

```
srs.public_methods.sort
```

Comment: To use gdal with ruby we need to intall library called "libgdal-ruby".  Here script that I work with osr spacial reference. sudo apt-get install libgdal-ruby. With irb we need to require 'gdal/gdal' and 'gdal/ogr'.

Comment: Yup, the GDAL/OSR bindings look good, but the documentation is sparse. You can normally translate examples from Python over to Ruby without too much hassle (just subtle differences in the method names).

Comment: How do you install this gem extension (the osr part)? I successfully installed the 'gdal' gem, I have all the firmware and so on installed in my mac. But not able to access the `osr` bit

Answer (score 2):

FYI, http://prj2epsg.org/ lets you lookup PRJ files and get the SRID / EPSG code.

**Update:** Site is down. See this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372381/is-there-an-alternative-to-prj2epsg-org